# Is OrmLite truly database agnostic?

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework-5, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am new to Service Stack and OrmLite, and was exploring ORMLite as an alternative to Entity Framework. 2 questions I have about this:
- The reason EF appeals to me is the ability to separate the database operations and the business data model into separate layers
- EF can run with whatever you specify in the connection string of the config file. ORMLite seems to have different flavors for different databases, and that concerns me because I don't want to have to make code changes repeatedly.

Am I understanding things correctly? Please clarify

Thanks

Suraj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OrmLite does support multiple database providers through the use of **DialectProvider's**.

Basically whenever some RDBMS's deviate from the norm and require special attention, than this functionality is factored out into a Dialect provider so it can provide bespoke functionality and the default behavior be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

Though there is no such thing as being "database agnostic". A product may conform to a standard (SQL92 for example), but even that is not a guarantee that its fully implemented for that standard.

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) setting a connection to a different database/backing store would be just setting a different connection string and dialect provider in the connection factory, so this means that changing databases would not be too terribly difficult.

As far as an official list, [this](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/AllDialectsTest/Main.cs) was the closest I could find.

- SqlLite
- SqlServer
- MySql
- PostgreSQL
- FirebirdSql

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too. Thanks !

Comment: This refers to Java's OrmLite, not ServiceStack's C# OrmLite - 2 completely different products.

Comment: Well, there you go. I missed that tidbit entirely. I'll update the answer.

Comment: There's also an Oracle RDBMS Dialect Provider as well and a NuGet package for each DB

Answer (score 0):

Having worked on an ORM in the past I can tell you ORMs are not in fact "database agnostic".  Rather, ORMs attempt to be as database agnostic as possible and usually have a target set.  They will love you of course if you help add in support for a database not on the list.

For example, it is unlikely that ORM supports NoSQL databases (e.g. Redis, CouchDB)[but not impossible], native XML (e.g. eXist) or object oriented databases (e.g. Zope).  For the most part, these technologies target RDBMSs, and they usually do it pretty well.

Since this is built on Java, you'll probably have a lot of options - anything that will connect with JDBC will probably be supported or leave open the possibility of extension.

In the heart of these tools the SQL and functions you write is parsed and made digestable by the underlying database.  In theory any database could be used.

StingyJack found the exact databases supported. MySQL, Postgres, Microsoft SQL Server, H2, Derby, HSQLDB, and Sqlite.

Now keep in mind, another feature is that new databases generally can be supported by working with the interfaces in the code - so if you don't see a database you want, you could potentially copy another module and modify it until it complies.

Becuase these tools are built following a standard pattern, that pattern is reapplied and adapted to each database.  Hence as that list grows, you should be able to safely expect the same support for each new database.

That being said, its a good idea to watch the activity of any open source project, because support can trail off if it is underutilized or undercommited before it reaches a mature state.

This particular ORM appears to be SQL based, so don't expect expanded support to cover non-relational databases.